# Formal definition of member function

Tags: c++, function, member

I'm reading the N3797 working draft and I would like to know what is the definition of **member function** (I.e. what does member function mean). My current understanding is member function is a function declared into the class or namespace scope. But what is the actual definition of member function?

I would like to clear how does `member function` combination of words must be interpreted? It is a member function of class or a namespace or a member function of something else?

For example: clause 12 named as `Special member function`.

Where is it explain into the standard?

Comment: _'But what is the actual definition of member function?'_ Giving it an actual body inside of this class or namespace scope.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I clarified that I would like to know what does member function mean. I already know what does function definition(declaration) mean.

Comment: If you have the draft then it should simply be a matter of looking at the table of contents and seeing that under `Classes` there is a section called `Member Functions` or simply do a search. Am I missing something about the question?

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Sure I'm using table of contents. But I want to clear that definition.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv You need to be more specific about what you don't understand because as the question stands it looks like you are asking people to search the document for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's spelled out in §9.3/1.

> Functions declared in the definition of a class, excluding those declared with a `friend` specifier (11.3), are
>   called member functions of that class. A member function may be declared `static` in which case it is a *static*
>   member function of its class (9.4); otherwise it is a *non-static* member function of its class (9.3.1, 9.3.2).

Comment: But what about namespace member function? Does function declared into namespace scope is namespace member function?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, "member function" always means "a function which is a member of a class". The standard does not use "member function" to denote a function that is a member of a namespace.

Comment: But if we consider the 3.4.1/6 we have: `A name used in the definition of a function following the function’s declarator-id that is a member of namespace N`. I'm thinking that the function considered as a **member function of namespace** in that example. It is really confused. Can you clarify?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv It's a function and it's a member of the namespace but as far as I'm aware, the term "member function" is not used for such a function.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv clause 12 is about members of classes only, which you'll see if you read all the sections individually.

Comment: The quoted passage is the definition of "member function" in the standard.  It is the _only_ meaning that the expression "member function" has (unless there is a defect in the standard).  The fact that a function is a member of a namespace doesn't make it a "member function" (although it would have been better if the standard has said "a function declared at namespace scope", rather than "member of a namespace").

Answer (score 2):

Section `§ 9.3.1` of the standard :

> **Member Functions**
>
> Functions declared in the definition of a class, excluding those
>   declared with a friend specifier (
>   11.3 ), are called member functions of that class.